# Make URL unreadable

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm making a script where you can upload a sample picture, and download it.. But when I try to download a file it looks like; http://localhost/uploads/file/filename.png

Thats not really safe I guess for hackers.. They can just put in image.png image1.png etc.. So what I exactly need help for is, how can I make a link unreadable like; http://localhost/asdajh1728dsa871nsada87 or similar like that one, or anything unreadable.

I just use rawurlencode.

Im struggling for days, help is really appreciated.

If it is possible via a .htaccess file its also welcome :)

Comment: Are you trying to prevent hackers from guessing your image files? or are you trying to prevent hackers from putting bad things into your images files?

Comment: How about using random images names instead or using DB to store it..

Comment: I'm trying to prevent hackers to access the content of my uploads folder.. You can guess like /uploads/filename1.png and if it exists than you can see it, but I don't want to have anything like that.. Just a safe url so they can't see the folder/file structure.

Comment: Just to be clear - that will not prevent hackers from accessing your files.

Comment: If you're looking to prevent unauthorized access to your uploaded content, I'd suggest looking into applying authentication rather than 'fixing' your issue with obscure file names

Comment: @TaykTaykCFKayahan in any case, an attacker will be able to spam all combination available, even more if the length of your key is always the same

Comment: Encrypt the name of the file using a key that you have on your server. `base64_encode` encrypted string, and use it when sending the url to the file or when including the file. When you receive a request, decrypt the string that's supposed to be the file name. If decrypting fails or file isn't there - you know someone tried to access something they were not supposed to.

Comment: Where are we on this question ? If you received an answer that satisfies your needs, please mark it

Answer (score 0):

it is possible with [fpassthru](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php#example-2236), this snippet converts requests for `/images/$encoded_path` into `show_image.php?img=$encoded_path`, and lets the php return the data and decode the path

php:

```
$decoded=some_decoding($_GET['img']);
// open the file in a binary mode
$name = './uploads/file/'.$decoded;
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// dump the picture and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

and in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule    ^images/([0-9a-z]+)/?$    show_image.php?img=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: But what If I also have other file extensions ? Please for a fast reply though:)

Comment: I haven't covered how you could encode and decode your images, I leave this work to you :-), you could include the extension in the encoding if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to "scramble" you file names, use md5 with file name and time stamp.

```
$filename = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
```

That will give you a random 16*2 long string.
Simply save the file with the random filename.
You can change 16 to 32 or 64 to create a longer names.

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply, I will try to apply it :)